# How to verify a PowerShell script is running using c#

Tags: c#, powershell

I Have launched a `PowerShell` script using C# asynchronously. At some point of time I want to verify is script is still running using C#. Please suggest how could I verify if script is running I have tried using `Process.GetProcessesByName("scriptname")` by seems not working.

Comment: I don't know whether this is possible but it sounds like a bad idea - why do you need that?

Comment: @Martin let say i have an api to launch a script and may be script take so long to execute so in mean time if i would like to check status of script(say running, stopped) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using the `Pipeline.InvokeAsync` method:

> After it is called, it changes the state of the pipeline to Running.
>   When the method is completed, it changes the state of pipeline to one
>   of following: Completed: The pipeline state is Completed if the
>   pipeline invocation completed successfully. Failed: The pipeline state
>   is Failed if the pipeline invocation failed or one of the commands in
>   the pipeline threw a terminating error. Stopped: The pipeline state is
>   Stopped if the pipeline was stopped by calling Stop or StopAsync.

[Source.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.pipeline.invokeasync(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thank you so much.